# Executing HDFS commands through Java

Tags: java, hadoop, command-line, hdfs

So I have to run HDFS commands like `hdfs dfs –ls /some_folder` through Java, but I don't know how to do it and the online explanations are so confusing.

Can someone give me a simple explanation about it and some actual code I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop actually supports reading HDFS directories and files through its `FileSystem` class which given a directory can actually recursively read its contents.

So for example in my system I have this directory called `wc_out` with the following contents (which are two files named `_SUCCESS` and `part-r-00000`) that we can see through the command line:

[image]

I used the the `FileSystem` class to pinpoint the directory I am passing to the following program as an argument and the `LocatedFileStatus` class in order to retrieve certain fields (such as the file path, if it is a directory or not, its size length, and its permission) of information for each file (you can see what you can retrieve yourself through the API docs [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/LocatedFileStatus.html)):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.RemoteIterator;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Dir_ls
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        Path input_dir = new Path(args[0]);

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        if(fs.exists(input_dir))
        {
            RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> file_list = fs.listFiles(input_dir, true);

            System.out.println("\nContents of the " + args[0] + " directory:");
            System.out.println("==========================================\n");

            while(file_list.hasNext())
            {
                LocatedFileStatus file = file_list.next();

                System.out.println(file.getPath() + " | " + file.isDirectory() +  " | " + file.getLen() + " | " + file.getPermission() + "\n");
            }   

            System.out.println("==========================================");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Directory named \"" + args[0] + "\" doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

So we can check that the output of the program is correct and (info-wise) identical with the command line information we get through the `hadoop fs -ls dir_name` command:

[image]